# How to call a view function with argument from template and return a python object in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

Here is the questions 
now I want call a view function from template/html with argument 
the function most like

```
def function(PageToken,ID):
  '''Do Something Here'''
  comments = [[User1,Comment1],[User2,Comment2]]
  return comments
```

And how I call this function and Use like

```
{%for comment in comments %}
  <li>                          
    {{comment.1}}
    {{comment.2}}
  </li>
 {%endfor%}
```

And I dont want 
Reload the page 
how to do that

Comment: You can do that using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: no need for closing the question, it has clear reason and code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define your own custom template filter that takes arguments.

```
# in custom_tags.py  
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def build_comments(pagetoken, id):
    # build comments 
    return comments # it can also be queryset  
register.assignment_tag(build_comments)
```

in template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{% build_comments pagetoken id as comments %}
{% for comment in comments %}
    <li>                          
       {{comment.1}}
       {{comment.2}}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

full documentation ---> [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

Comment: thanks you answer is very useful for me
but call pass more then 2 argument 
like {{a|cut:"a" "tt"}} or {{a|cut:"a","tt"}}?

Comment: @MingChu yes, you can pass so many arguments as you want. `{% build_comments arg1 arg2 arg3 ... as comments %}`

Comment: Thanks that's what I need